# iOS Framework to have storyboard with custom view controller which inherited class is defined in app bundle

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, storyboard

I created reusable **framework** with **storyboard**.

There I have `view controller` scene.

I have most of the functionality of this view controller in class `BaseViewController.swift` (defined inside framework).

But I would like to **extend** this BaseViewController in **each app linking against this framework** and have some `MyInheritedViewController`.

How can I make this storyboard view controller to use MyInheritedViewController **from application bundle**, and in the same time be **defined inside storyboard in framework**.

Maybe there is other solution to this problem? I have thinking about **delegation** from `BaseViewController.viewDidLoad()` and have `delegate?.baseViewControllerLoaded()` or `delegate?.baseViewControllerDidAppear()`, etc.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, that would make your framework dependent on the app, and the app dependent on the framework. Even if possible, that's a bad idea.

Comment: Yeah but I have some base functionality in framework, and want to customize it in application. There should be possibility to extend base functionality from framework in application. And taking into account that I have to specify name of the view controller's class in storyboard how I can achieve this? I could write entire view controller in code without storyboard, but it is really the only workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a custom iOS framework and use the Storyboard init , but from outside the framework when try to navigate in side the storyboard of the framework it's didn't work. But if I added the view of the framework view controller in the project in which I add the framework I can see the UI of the framework viewcontroller but the problem is to navigation its not navigating to another view or button is not clickable still I add view as a sub child of the framework view .If you have any examples how to navigate inside the framework storyboard please let me know.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35805955)